# how can i make django sign up form? (django 1.11.8)

Tags: python, django, forms

I want to make a sign up form.

I made login form.

I am using auth_user. (django default table)

and I had to add more columns, so I made a new table and referenced auth_user table by foreign key.

and I'm going to make sign up form. How can I make it?

In django default sign up page, it only requires id, pw.

(In sign form, user must input email, questions for when he(she) find password, address, birthday, etc..)

Comment: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/02/18/how-to-create-user-sign-up-view.html

Comment: Now I'm using 'profile model'. But if I add @receiver ~ and Log in, the application returns error.

Comment: (1054, "Unknown column 'profile.user_id' in 'field list'")

Comment: You need to update database. It looks like you don't have user_id column in db.

Comment: umm.. Does profile model must have user_id column?

Comment: You should be the one to decide :)

Comment: I added 'user_id' column in profile model,

Comment: ERRORS:
main.Profile.user_id: (models.E006) The field 'user_id' clashes with the field 'user' from model 'main.profile'.

Comment: this error returns ㅠ.ㅠ